# Android UI: setting background color for Button prevents it from highlighting upon press

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to eliminate the gap between buttons in a layout. I'm doing it by setting background color for a style and applying that style to my buttons. This eliminates the highlighting upon press, which I of course need. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399593/setting-list-item-background-color-loses-highlighting) is a solution to this problem, but it requires extra actions to be taken with Java code. Can I make it statically, only with XMLs?

Also, if there is any other way to remove the gap without changing the other aspects of button's appearance - please suggest. The only requirement is it should be done with XML (however, if no other options exist, I can inherit Button class).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [StateList xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) for background of your button